# jquery ajax anonymous function when trying to pass form data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, file-upload

I am trying to pass a Input file field through a jquery ajax and i am getting an anonymous function in my chrome inspector console which says it is because of the line in my script:
 $.ajax({

Heres the code i run after i have my

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $("#sendCoverImageForm").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault()
          var mForm = $("#sendFormOne").serialize()
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{% url 'ajax_coverimage' %}",
              data: mForm,
              success: function(data){  
                console.log(data)
                 $("#CoverImageModal").modal("hide");
              },
              error: function(data){
                var obj = data.responseJSON
                $("#modalMessage").html("<p style='color:red;'>" + obj + "</p>")
              },
           });
        });
```

If i run the script before the

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the console i get
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - relating to the top line on the script. I then run the script and it works and puts the file into my model but then the page renders "Success `<filename>`" in the DOM rather then the Console.

I'm a noob with jquery so any help would be gladly recieved!

Comment: In the Console it says ` POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/cover_image/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)jquery.min.js:4 n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery.min.js:4 n.extend.ajax(index):579 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle `

Comment: You can't upload a file with data from `.serialize()` you'll have to use the FormData object.

Answer (score 0):

The `$()` is equivalent to the jQuery Object `jQuery()`, wich in both cases will treat the statements between parentheses in the jQuery function scope.
This explains why the script will raise an Uncaught ReferenceError before you include jQuery src, since the `$` sign isn't defined yet.

As musa said, you shuold use the FormData object, but you should keep in mind that in IE it's only supported from IE10+, you can however use a plugin to support older browsers as the amount of code you'll be writing to support them is unpleasant for people just starting out in the JavaScript world but you should learn how to do it afterwards, see [filedropjs](http://filedropjs.org/) for example.

Here's a [tutorial](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) for using FormData (don't mind the PHP).
Hope this helps!

Comment: `data you are sending is supposed to be in JSON format.` where did you get that from?

Comment: i guess that's a little bit misleading, i ll change that.